# How to format multi dimensional arrays as in a given format

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with some keys, here what I need is to merge values at same keys e.g., scorecard value for key 117 & 107 should merged as given below in the output array.

```
$input_array = array (

38 => array
    (
        117 => array
            (
                'scorecard' => array
                    (
                        0 => 'q4'
                    ),

                'business_plan' => array
                    (
                        0 => 'q4'
                    )
            ),

        107 => array
            (
                'scorecard' => array
                    (
                        0 => 'q1'
                    ),

                'business_plan' => array
                    (
                        0 => 'q2'
                    )
            ),

    ),

53 => array
    (
        373 => array
            (            
                'scorecard' => array
                    (
                        0 => 'q4'
                    ),

                'business_plan' => array
                    (
                        0 => 'q1'
                    )
            ),

        110 => array
            (       
                'scorecard' => array
                    (
                        0 => 'q4',
                        0 => 'q3'
                    ),

                'business_plan' => array
                    (
                        0 => 'q4'
                    ),

                'marketing_plan' => array
                    (
                        0 => 'q3',
                        1 => 'q4'
                    )

            )

    ),

318 => array
    (
        2279 => array
            (             
                'scorecard' => array
                    (
                        0 => 'q4'
                    )
            )

    )

 );
```

Output array will contain values like this:-

```
 Array
 (
[38] => Array
    (
     [scorecard] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => q4
                        [1] => q1
                    )
     [business_plan] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => q4
                        [1] => q2
                    )            
    )

[53] => Array
    (

        [scorecard] => Array
            (
                 [0] => q4
                 [1] => q3
            )

        [business_plan] => Array
            (
                [0] => q1
                [0] => q4
            )
        [marketing_plan] => Array
            (
                [0] => q3
                [1] => q4
            )
    )

[318] => Array
    (
        [scorecard] => Array
            (
                [0] => q4
            )        
    )

 )
```

Comment: have you try anything ?

Comment: yes, but I'm not able to figure out how to compare keys e.g scorecard key for 117 & 118 etc.

Comment: `foreach($array as $key => $value) {}`

Comment: foreach($score_board as $key1=>$val){
  foreach($val as $key2=>$val2){
    
    // here how do I merge value at same key.
     
    }
   }

Comment: @kapil : same key is not possible in same array : http://prntscr.com/deejz3

Comment: there is same key at different key e.g, at key 117 & 107 etc. both have scorecard

Comment: Please provide input array in valid format so that i can directly run it into my local system to debug.

Comment: @RaviRoshan: I have edited the question with valid input format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by combining [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php):

```
$result = array_map(function ($item) {
    return array_reduce($item, 'array_merge_recursive', []);
}, $input_array);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2dc336311592ec9e823ff5af205bba60e9bac208).